# Increasing serial console suspend time in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, serial-port, kernel, android-source, tty

I want to increase suspend time for serial console which is approximately 5 mins right now.

For disabling the suspend I'm using `no_console_suspend` in `BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE`. But ultimate goal is to increase timeout for suspend. Where can I look for changing the suspend time in kernel?

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand your problem. The above mentioned option just delays console suspension to the time when it’s not possible anymore to have it running.

Comment: If we don’t add no_console_suspend then serial suspends after X minutes. I want to increase that number of X minutes so that it gets suspended after some additional time.

Comment: Generally speaking the suspension of the console is arbitrary, what you are trying to do won’t be anyhow guaranteed. And *minutes* sounds very suspicious. Are you actually talking about suspend-to-disk?